# How to Change the default SharePoint ICON for SharePoint Sites opens in new tabs and in browser start address

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, 2016

Hi How to Change the default SharePoint ICON for SharePoint Sites opens in new tabs and in browser start address.
I tried to add favicons under head tag of masterpage but its not changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use jQuery to change the icon.Add the code into master page.

```
<script src="http://sp/Shared%20Documents/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () { 
    $('#favicon').attr('href', '/Shared%20Documents/Google-Chrome-Google-Chrome.ico');
});
```

Test result:

[image: strong text]